# c# outlook plug-in, add column to search result

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

I am trying to write a outlook plug-in that adds a new column to the search result, which shows the entire path to the folder of the found e-mail.

Is it possible to add a new column to the existing search and if yes how? Do you have some tutorials or ebooks that teach the basic knowledge of office plug-in programming?

thank you

PS: This seems to be a really basic task, but I haven't written a office plug-in before. My experience is limited to some small WPF applications.

Comment: does nobody have a idea?

Comment: did you find any solution to your question asked in '12?  I'm looking for a similar task to complete.